# How do I keep website footer on bottom of the window?

Tags: css

Coding footer naively, if there's not enough content, then there will be empty space between footer and bottom of page. I would like to get rid of this and move footer to the bottom of the window.

On the other hand when there is more content, I want the content to push the footer down (so position: fixed; bottom: 0; won't do).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I had to do this for perqworks.com, it was a pain because it added two super wrapper divs to every page. Ugly in my opinion. Encourage you to say no to the designers on this one.

Comment: So two super wrapper divs is more important than the result? Get your priorities straight.

Comment: Sounds like a sound argument from a designer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a newer one, the CSSStickyFooter:

> http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's a great tutorial at http://www.htmltutorialsandtips.com/css-sticky-footer that explains how to do that. It goes through a basic HTML markup and the css used to style it for that effect. It's easy to follow and does a good job explaining how the CSS actually works to get the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result by:

1. Declaring a height value for the `<body>` & `<html>` tags
2. Declaring a `minimum-height` value to the nested wrapper element, usually the element which wraps all your descendant elements contained within the body structure

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWwqqB)

```js
$("#addBodyContent").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo(".flex-col:first-of-type");
});

$("#resetBodyContent").on("click", function() {
  $(".flex-col p").remove();
});

$("#addFooterContent").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo("footer");
});

$("#resetFooterContent").on("click", function() {
  $("footer p").remove();
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 91%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-col {
    flex: 1 1;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.flex-btn-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: .7s;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dark {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.light {
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.light:hover {
    color: white;
}

.dark:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="addBodyContent" class="dark btn">Add Content</button>
        <button id="resetBodyContent" class="dark btn">Reset Content</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-col">
      lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<footer>
    <div class="flex-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="addFooterContent" class="light btn">Add Content</button>
        <button id="resetFooterContent" class="light btn">Reset Content</button>
    </div>
    lorem ipsum dolor...
</footer>
```